# AWS Lambda return a file

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I'm reading a CSV file from S3 using Lambda and want to return that file to the caller of the lambda function. I don't want to print the file through `outputstream` - I want to return the actual file. Is there a way to do this? I get the S3 file like this:

```
override def handleRequest(inputStream: InputStream,
                             outputStream: OutputStream,
                             context: Context): Unit = {
    ...
    val s3File = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, bucketKey)
}
```

How can I return the actual file (as opposed to converting it to String and printing via `outputStream`)?

Comment: You can't do that. Your `file` handle only has meaning in the context of your lambda function, it means nothing outside of it.

Comment: What do you mean with the **_"actual file"_**? Who will call the lambda & what will do with the **_"file"_**? - I believe you have a big misunderstanding of what does a `java.io.File` mean, what `S3` is and works and in general about how networking works.

Comment: How is the Lambda function being invoked?

Comment: If you have a api gateway + lambda setup, then it can be achieved as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-lambda.html)

Comment: It is being invoked through an API Gateway. @Rishikesh Darandale That links shows the API gateway side of things, but what code does the lambda function need to actually return it?

Comment: @covfefe, I posted an answer how it could have been done in `nodejs`. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

The above can be done using `nodejs` aws lambda with `express` server. You could use aws provided [package](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express)

```
// lambda.js
'use strict'
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

exports.handler = (event, context) => { awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context) }


// app.js
// refer the examples for complete code
// https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/blob/master/examples/basic-starter/app.js
...
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  s3.getObject({Bucket: myBucket, Key: myFile},function(err,data){

    if (err) {
      // report error and return the server error
      return res.status(500).send("Error!");
    }

    // set the http Headers
    res.set("Content-Length",data.ContentLength)
       .set("Content-Type",data.ContentType);

    // send the data
    res.send(data.Body);

  });

});
...
```

PS: I have not tested the above code.